# How do I sum the values of data-price from different input types?

Tags: html, jquery, function

I am designing a form that will hopefully be able to take user input and sum a total for the client to see as they go. Ive tried to use the data-price attribute to collect the values but i just cant seem to get it to work!
Any pointers as to where I'm going wrong would be greatly greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>My test page</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <link href="form-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1">
            <div id="go">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="one" class="abc" data-price="1600"/>Live Band
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="two" class="abc" data-price="400"/>DJ
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="three" class="abc" data-price="500"/>Acoustic
                </label>
            </div>

            <div id="example" class="container">
                <select id="place">
                    <option value="">pick</option>
                    <option value="a" data-price="100">a</option>
                    <option value="b" data-price="200">b</option>
                    <option value="c" data-price="300">c</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div id="result" class="container"></div>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function validate(){
            var $selected = $('#go','#place').children(":selected");
            var sum =0;
            
            $selected.each(function(){
                sum += $(this).data('price') || 0;
            });

            $('#result').html(sum === 0 ? '' : sum +'$');
        }
        validate();         
        
        $('#go, #place').on('change',function(){
            validate();
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. "cant seem to get it to work" is not a great description of the problem. Please supply a more thorough explanation of expected behaviour and where it breaks. As it stands now I don't know which part isn't working as you expect it to. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code, which stops you from calculating the `sum` correctly:

1. `#go` is not an input element, and therefore will never fire the `change` event. To observe change events on all your inputs, use `$('#go input, #place')` instead.
2. You are accessing the value of checked radio buttons and selected option incorrectly:

   ```
   $('#go','#place').children(":selected")
   ```

   This is incorrect, as (1) you are joining the selectors incorrectly, and (2) checkbox/radio buttons don't have the `:selected` pseudo class. In order to retrieve the selected radio buttons and select option, you can perform this instead:

   - To access the checked radio button, use `$('#go input:checked')`
   - To access the selected option, use `$('#place option:selected')`

See updated example based on your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function validate() {
    var sum = 0;
    sum += +$('#go input:checked').data('price') || 0;
    sum += +$('#place option:selected').data('price') || 0;

    $('#result').html(sum === 0 ? '' : sum + '$');
  }
  validate();

  $('#go input, #place').on('change', function() {
    validate();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
  <div id=go>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="one" class="abc" data-price="1600">Live Band</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="two" class="abc" data-price="400">DJ</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="three" class="abc" data-price="500">Acoustic</label>
  </div>
  <div id="example" class="container">
    <select id="place">
      <option value="">pick</option>
      <option value="a" data-price="100">a</option>
      <option value="b" data-price="200">b</option>
      <option value="c" data-price="300">c</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>

<div id="result" class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thats really helpful thank you very much. Your corrections worked perfectly, and I think i understand why.